# stacked ggplot for data coverage over time

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I'm working with data from a database, that get's refreshed quite frequently and I'd like to have a graphical representation of the time frame when there is good data coverage, version the lag to the actually date when the data was last refreshed.

```
# data example
name <- c("DATA1", "DATA2", "DATA3")
start <- c("1988-01-01","1994-01-01", "1988-01-01")
end <- c("2013-12-31","2013-05-31","2014-03-31")
refresh <- c("2014-02-28","2013-07-25","2014-05-20")
mydata <- data.frame(name, start, end, refresh)

# data preview
mydata
   name      start        end    refresh
1 DATA1 1988-01-01 2013-12-31 2014-02-28
2 DATA2 1994-01-01 2013-05-31 2013-07-25
3 DATA3 1988-01-01 2014-03-31 2014-05-20
```

I then reshape the data (I'm not sure if this is strictly necessary:

```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(reshape)   
   mdata <- melt(mydata, measure.vars = c("start", "end", "refresh"))
```

So far I've only managed to plot the start - refresh dates like this:

```
ggplot(mdata, aes(as.Date(value, "%Y-%m-%d"), factor(name, levels=name))) +
geom_line(size=6) +
xlab("") + ylab("") +
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Problems:

1: I seem to get a lot of warning messages, i.e.

```
Warning messages:
1: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
2: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
3: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
4: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

**2: What I'd really would like is having a black bar for start to end and a red bar for end to refresh**

P.S. I only use the `factor` bit, because I want the data to be sorted in the same order of my original table, otherwise they will be ordered alphabetically by table name (my real table names are different to this example).

Comment: what I have also come across is `Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path).`. However, there was data for this item in the table, but it then ends up blank in the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because in `factor(name, levels=name))` there are duplicated `name`s. You'd probably want `factor(name, levels=unique(name)))`

If you want to use `geom_line` you need to duplicate some of your data. You could use `geom_linerange` instead:

```
mydata[,2:4] <- lapply(mydata[,2:4], as.Date)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=factor(name, levels=unique(name)))) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=start, ymax=end, colour="period1"), size=5) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=end, ymax=refresh, colour="period2"), size=5) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_manual(name="period", values=c("period1"="black", "period2"="red")) +
  xlab("name")
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, I only need to figure out how to append the period bit.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I obviously have to create an additional variable, which contains "period1" and "period2"!?

Comment: Sorry, I understand now!

Comment: How am I getting a vertical line at a certain date on top of this? `geom_vline` and `geom_hline` don't seem to work.

Comment: Add `geom_hline(yintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("2003-01-01")))`.

Comment: Thanks, had forgotten about that it needs the `as.numeric` bit